# How to write gtest unittest for my own classes in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have defined my own class DoubleMatrix in C++. How can I write gtest unittests for it with different error messages, e.g. dimension mismatch or number of mismatches?

I need to realize smth like this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
  EXPECT_EQ(x[i], y[i]) << "Vectors x and y differ at index " << i;
}
```

but it should be calling like this:

```
DoubleMatrix a, b;
EXPECT_EQ(a, b)
```

or

```
DoubleMatrix a, b;
double epsilon = 0.0001;
EXPECT_NEAR(a, b, epsilon)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be these errors exceptions thrown from your class?

Comment: no, my class is like a struct, it has only constructor and some parameters.

Comment: I guess you already had a look here [gtest primer](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer)

Comment: And how do you expect should gtest be helpful with this? Testing clients for correct usage of your class? Then [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) might be useful in addition.

Comment: May be you should show some code with your approach, detailing what you want to achieve, and where you have problems.

Comment: Yes. I have just edited my question.

Comment: `EXPECT_EQ(a, b)`: So did you define an equality test operator for your `DoubleMatrix` class? Otherwise `EXPECT_EQ()` won't work.

Comment: Error messages at compile time??

Comment: Seems you've started looking inside. The general approach with [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is to modify your testing target (`DoubleMatrix`) until it fits your expectations, not to write test cases that can deal with the targets interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom predicates to do the same.

You can check https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md for details. (check **Predicate Assertions for Better Error Messages** section in the link)

For example, you can have a function:

```
bool foo(DoubleMatrix a, DoubleMatrix b) {
// do the comparison and return true or false }
```

Use this via EXPECT_PRED2(foo, a, b);